# Python: Separating asyncio coroutine declaration from event looping/execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, coroutine

**Python version: 3.5.2**

I'm trying to implement an easy to use interface using asyncIO for my end users.

In my model, the end user defines an ***async*** coroutine that operates on singular object(s).

e.g.,
***user_func(addr_object, property_object)***

Now, I would like to do something like this...

**User Code:**

*calling this file "user.py"*

````
# instantiating my_api object
batch_runner = my_api.BatchRunner()

# coro_list can have more than one user defined function
coro_list = [user_func(addr_object, property_object)]

# this method takes care of creating the eventloop and running it
batch_runnner.run(coro_list)


# all user defined coroutines live in this file "user.py"
async def user_func(addr_object, property_object):
    ``` operate on the objects
    # await on some operation
````

*P.S.: addr_object and property_object can be assigned to **None** in user.py to keep Python happy*

**My API code:**

*# calling this file "my_api.py"*

```
class BatchRunner(object):
...
    def run(self, coro_list):
        new_coro_list = list()
        # user can define multiple coroutines, but same type and length of input arguments on all of them
        for coros in coro_list:
            # Say I've 10 different addr_objects for example
            for addr_obj in addr_obj_list:
                # and say another 5 property_objects
                for prop_obj in prop_obj_list:
                    # how to modify coro_list to work on each of these addr_obj and prop_obj?
                    # while maintaining reference to the user defined coroutine in user.py?
                    new_coro_list.append(coros(addr_obj, prop_obj)

        eventloop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        eventloop.run_until_complete(new_coro_list)
```

**My questions are:**

- Is it possible to maintain reference to a coroutine object declared
  in another file **(user.py)** and modify the value of its input arguments before actual eventloop execution inside of **my_api.py**?
  i.e., same function call, but with modified argument values.
- If that is not possible, is there a better way to hide the iteration logic under the hood?
  (Could be using **kwargs with user function name being passed as a string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
def get_args():
    for i in range(10):
        for c in "ABCD":
            yield i, c

def batch_runner(funcs):
    tasks = [func(*args) for func in funcs for args in get_args()]
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    return loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
```

usage:

```
async def user_func1(i, c):
    print(">U1", i, c)
    await asyncio.sleep(i / 10)
    print("<U1", i, c)
    return("U1", i, c)    

async def user_func2(i, c):
    print(">U2", i, c)
    await asyncio.sleep(i / 5)
    print("<U2", i, c)
    return("U2", i, c)    

results = batch_runner([user_func1, user_func2])
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you! Its a great feeling to see a working solution that is several lines shorter than my original question. :)


One more question:

If the user_funcs had a **kwargs as the 3rd positional argument, how to maintain context of that as well? (No manipulation necessary, but needs to passed in during batch_runner(...)).

Comment: `func(*args, **kwargs)` ?